# Unifying multiple sample data (meta-analysis)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, variance, inference, meta-analysis

I would like to unify multiple sample data (of different sizes) into some "unified sample" to evaluate its collective variance. Is this something statisticians do? I thought of unifying multiple samples in the following way :

1.From each data value, reduce the average of the sample it belongs to

2.Then, collect all these modified values from all samples, into a unified sample

I have a good reason to believe that the unified-sample generated this way will distribute normally. Than, I could evaluate the variance of the unified sample and compare it to variances of other unified samples (say, with F-test). The problem I see with this approach is that the values in the unified sample are not independent, since each of them was created by reducing the sample average from the original value….
I'll be happy to hear your thoughts, suggestions about this.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you are looking to accomplish. It seems like you want to take the average (and measure of variance like SE) of a group of values and compare them with the average/ SE from another group. Is this correct? If so, this definitely can be done but there are assumptions that may or may not be valid. Working with a statistician may help expedite things as they can see your data and answer questions you may have.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case each sample data is actually a set of 7-8 different values. I have 5 sample data like these , so in total there is little less that 40 measurements  that I want to unify somehow.  You can think of it as 5 different experiments each generating 7-8 measurements. I am asking if it makes sense unifying the data after reducing sample average from each measurement .